# Embedding an external site inside a joomla site

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

A customer asked me to embed an external site inside an existing Joomla 1.5 site.

I thought to use the Joomla wrapper, but the problem is that the external site has a zoom function that permits to see in 100% width/height and, using wrapper, zoom would be limited to iframe size instead of all the page.

Is there a better way to embed an external site in Joomla 1.5?

Comment: My recommendation is to move from Joomla 1.5.  It's old and out of it's lifecycle.  Your best bet is to move to 2.5 as 3.1 is still a bit buggy and isn't quite deployment ready yet.  The components/plugins/extensions for J1.5 are also deprecated and are getting more and more limited as time goes on.

That said, to the best of my knowledge, a wrapper will be your best bet, is there any reason for doing this as opposed to just sending the user to the other site?

Comment: The customer does not want to change Joomla version and wants the external site to be embedded as if it was realized inside his Joomla

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, unfortunately, a wrapper will be your best bet to keep things tidy and working within the existing Joomla site.  I am interested to see what other solutions come up from this though.  Good luck!

Comment: Can you tell us more about this external site? You may be able to seamlessly interweave the two, depending on it's structure. I've done this before a few times without needing to us the wrapper.

Comment: @betweenbrain the external site is made in Drupal7; i've already made a sync script to keep the users syncronized from Joomla to Drupal, the customer would like a single sign on... After that, the Drupal site should result embedded inside the Joomla as if it was part of Joomla site; there is a zoom function that, in Drupal site, puts it at 100%, with the iframe in Joomla it is not possible to achieve.